# How to highlight a given text in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, highlighting

I have the following phrase:

```
The birds fly in the sky near planes.
0123456789012345678901234567890123456
          1         2         3
```

How can I highlight `in the sky` with TinyMce if I know the start(14) and end(23) of the phrase ?

I would like to use the `setRng` method but I didn't find any sample code.

Comment: Is it required to find the string by position, or would it be sufficient to find the string by the search-string?

Comment: Actually, I send the whole content if tinymce editor to a server. The server then replies back with some information. This information contains start and end of strings to be highlighted. Modifying the information sent by the server is not an option.

Comment: It seems that you implemented a real time collaboration editor on tinymce. Can you please enlight me how did you detect that the user selected a piece of text on tinymce? onselect does not work and I have been looking all over for an alternative. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with :

```
var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
var range = ed.selection.getRng();
range.setStart(textNode, start);
range.setEnd(textNode, end);
ed.selection.setRng(range);
```

Where :

- **textNode** can be a DOM text node that you can retrieve with `getElementById` or any other short-hand properties (`parent`, `nextSibling` etc)
- **start** and **end** are respectively the beginning and the end of the text you want to select

I prefer this solution because I only use the *tinyMCE* API. I don't rely on objects and methods that can change (in behavior, in bugs ...) from browser to browser.

Comment: Appreciate the thought process of only using the tinyMCE api and avoiding browser bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var start = document.getElementById('tinymce');
//var textNode = start.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].firstChild;
//edited
var textNode = start.getElementsByTagName('your_tag_where_you_have_the_text')[0].firstChild;
range.setStart(textNode, 14);
range.setEnd(textNode, 23);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

Comment: If I have no `p` inside my textarea,what should I do ?